Unexpected behavior with pthread read-write lock in a multiprocess multithreaded shared memory environment
I'm working in a multiprocess, multithreaded environment where I'm using a pthread_rwlock_t read-write lock stored in shared memory so that all processes can access it. Here's how I initialized the lock initially:
rw_lock = (pthread_rwlock_t *) ShmemAlloc(sizeof(pthread_rwlock_t));
if(pthread_rwlock_init(rw_lock, NULL)) {
    // Handle error
}

In this setup, Process A acquires a read lock like this:
lockStatus = pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock(rw_lock);
switch(lockStatus) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case EBUSY:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            pg_usleep(100);
            lockStatus = pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock(rw_lock);
            if(!lockStatus) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!lockStatus) {
            break;
        }
    case EINVAL:
    default:
        printf(ERROR, "COULD NOT GET SHARED LOCK");
        break;
}

After Process A acquires the read lock, Process B tries to acquire an exclusive (write) lock:
if(pthread_rwlock_wrlock(rw_lock)) {
    printf(ERROR, "COULD NOT GET EXCLUSIVE LOCK");
}

I expected that once Process A releases the read lock, Process B would acquire the exclusive lock.
However, I observed unexpected behavior:

Sometimes Process B acquires the lock after a long delay (5-30 seconds).
Other times, Process B never acquires the exclusive lock at all.

After reading the documentation, I modified the initialization to pass an attribute like this:
rw_lock = (pthread_rwlock_t *)ShmemAlloc(sizeof(pthread_rwlock_t));
pthread_rwlockattr_t attr;
pthread_rwlockattr_init(&attr);
pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

if(pthread_rwlock_init(rw_lock, &attr)) {
    pthread_rwlockattr_destroy(&attr);
    // Handle error
}

With this change, Process B consistently acquires the exclusive lock as expected after Process A releases the read lock.
My questions:

In the initial scenario (without PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED), how did Process B know that Process A held the shared lock? Was it waiting on some internal mechanism?
Why did Process B realize the lock was released in the second scenario (with PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) and not in the first? How does the pthread library signal to other processes that a lock has been released?

Any insights into the internal behavior of pthread_rwlock and how it works across processes would be appreciated.



In the initial scenario (without PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED), how did Process B know that Process A held the shared lock? Was it waiting
on some internal mechanism?


That's not specified or defined.  Presumably, though, it knew by looking at the lock data structure in shared memory.  And in those cases where B recognized that A had released the lock, it presumably knew that the same way.  It's unclear how it knew to look in those cases where it noticed the state change.


Why did Process B realize the lock was released in the second scenario (with PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) and not in the first? How
does the pthread library signal to other processes that a lock has
been released?


The lock needs to be configured for use across processes for its behavior to be defined when used concurrently by multiple processes.  (This is standard for pthreads objects that support multi-process use.)  You so configured the lock in the second scenario, but not in the first, so you got behavior according to the lock's specifications in the second scenario, and undefined behavior in the first.

Any insights into the internal behavior of pthread_rwlock and how it
works across processes would be appreciated.

Pthreads is first and foremost a specification.  There is a variety of implementations, for which internal details vary.  "How does it work internally?" is rarely a useful question for people who just want to use an implementation, and there is no universal answer anyway.  Generally, you should focus on using an API such as Pthreads according to its specifications, not on details of how those specifications are implemented.
If you insist, however, you can study the source of an open-source implementation, such as Glibc's.
